# using django-facebook to save facebook user friends

Tags: django, django-facebook

I am using django-facebook to have facebook connect functionality in my site.

Everything is great till now, however I am trying to save the friends list in my db when the signal facebook_user_registered is called using the function get_and_store_friends.

The problem is that current get_open_graph function requires the request object which the view function recieve and I am in facebook_user_registerd and have no access to a request object in that moment.

Is it possible to do in the registartion signal ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing this asyncronously using [Celery](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook#celery-performance-and-optimization). Django-facebook will automatically pull down users' friends on registration if you are using Celery and set the following in your settings.py:

```
FACEBOOK_STORE_FRIENDS = True
FACEBOOK_CELERY_STORE = True
```

At that point, each user will have a friends property which contains a list of FacebookUser objects with their facebook IDs and some minimal opengraph details.